# limitando o valor que poderá ser digitado no input

Tags: jquery, input

Tenho uma variavel php que tem um valor que varia dependendo do momento!! Exemplo

1º momento `$valor = 300`

2º momento `$valor = 20`

3º momento `$valor = 5300`

4º momento `$valor = 1300`

Tenho também um input, nesse input pode adicionar um valor qualquer, desde que ele seja abaixo do valor no momento que for digitar. Eis então o que quero fazer!! Caso alguém venha digitar um valor maior no input o valor automaticamente muda pro maximo e não para aquilo que foi digitado!!

Exemplo:

1º momento `$valor = 300` || Nesse primeiro momento o valor máximo do input poderá ser só 300!! Só que em vez de 300 o usuário digitou 301, na mesma hora eu quero que esses 301 vire 300, pois é o valor limite que o usuário possui!

Comment: Não entendi bem o papel do PHP. Como você mantém o estado entre os diferentes "momentos"? Com variável de sessão? O JavaScript/jQuery só executa depois que o PHP já terminou.

Comment: o php coloquei mais pra sinalizar que uso ele!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usando jQuery eu criei essa função que fica escutando o evento `keyup` (quando o usuário solta uma tecla). Dentro da função verifico o valor.

```js
$('#txtValor').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var valorMaximo = 300;

  if (event.target.value > valorMaximo)
    return event.target.value = valorMaximo;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Digite o valor: R$ <input type="text" id="txtValor">
```

Comment: Estranho, nao esta funcionado no meu pc o codigo!

Comment: Você está importando a lib do jQuery? Note que eu estou escutando o input com o id "txtValor".

Comment: sim sim!! coloquei tudo certinho!! Cheguei ate copiar seu código exatamente da forma que esta para testar e nem assim funcionou!

Comment: Se der erro de referência coloque código dentro da tag `<script>`no final da página ou use a função [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), por que talvez a página não foi carregada totalmente, aí a função não consegue encontrar o campo.

Comment: Coloquei no final e funcionou!! Obrigado!! Mas porque isso acontece?

Comment: Ivan, é porque acontece o seguinte: Você está tentando escutar um evento de um elemento que ainda não foi "carregado", como a função estava na parte de cima (antes do campo) ele não consegue enxergar o campo depois que carrega (porque tentou e não conseguiu na primeira). Usando uma dessas duas soluções funciona porque: 1) Usando o `$(document).ready()` ele só vai carregar seu script depois que a página estiver pronta. 2) O seu campo já foi carregado então o script enxerga o campo.